# Why are transparent composables in Jetpack Compose not completely transparent?

Tags: android, kotlin, user-interface, android-jetpack-compose, composable

In a project I am creating, I want to have a transparent floating button button in one of my screens.

The button should be of a color RGB(126,26,71), with 75% alpha channel.

But, when I create said button composable, it looks like this:
[As you can see, it has slightly white, transparent background as well](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nb8Bo.png)

This is how the composable is created:

```
FloatingActionButton(
       onClick = {//TODO},
       backgroundColor = MediumOpaquePurple, //the color I specified above
       elevation = FloatingActionButtonDefaults.elevation(Space8)
       ) 
   {
       Icon(
            imageVector = Icons.Default.Delete,
            contentDescription = "Delete notifications"
       )
   }
```

Weird thing is that when I use the same color for *ExtendedFloatingActionButton* composable, it looks perfectly fine and there's no white background in it.

Any help apprectiated.

Thanks

Comment: Does the `ExtendedFloatingActionButton` also have `elevation` set? I suspect `elevation` might have a hand in changing the color.

Comment: ^ That's what that is, actually. You're seeing the artifact from the elevation shadow through the translucent background. Ultimately, Compose is using the same basic APIs as the `View` framework, and that shadow glitch is from the hardware-accelerated shadow generated by a `RenderNode`.

Comment: Yes, the Extended FAB has the elevation set the same way as the regular FAB. The regular FAB also shows the shadow even without elevation parameter set. Thanks for helping.

Comment: I'm not very familiar with Compose yet, but I would imagine that both of those are going to have default elevations, even if you don't explicitly set them.

Comment: This is exactly what I just checked and tested. There is default elevation. Set it to `0.dp` and the issue with background color will be solved. `ExtendedFloatingActionButton` works a bit differently, though.

Comment: @PrimožIvančič Awesome, that did the trick, thanks a lot.

Comment: You might want to check the behavior when they're clicked. Normally, buttons animate their elevations when pressed/un-pressed.

Comment: Ah, I see. If you set `elevation(0.dp, 0.dp)`, that's the default and pressed elevations, so with both at zero, it won't animate.

Answer (score 0):

For `FloatingActionButton` the solution is to set `elevation(0.dp)`. Just omitting the call is not enough, because it has a default value of `6.dp`.

`ExtendedFloatingActionButton` acts a bit differently and does need this tweaking.